# Gunicorn ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I'm reading a book about TDD and Django and there's a deployment part. I have a problem trying to run gunicorn with the following command:

```
/root/sites/django_blog/virtualenv/bin/gunicorn --bind unix:/tmp/django_blog.socket django_blog.wsgi:application
```

It fails with the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_blog'
```

But when I activate my virtualenv and instead of writing the full pass to gunicorn I just go with:

```
gunicorn --bind unix:/tmp/django_blog.socket django_blog.wsgi:application
```

And everything works perfectly! The problem is I still need to run it the first way, because I wil use it in the nginx service file. I wrote about this error and tried a couple of solutions but they didn't work for me. I guess I have to do something with environment variables but I don't know what exactly.

Comment: try: `--chdir /root/sites`? For details: https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#chdir

Comment: @jojo thank you so much! It works! Had to go with --chdir /root/sites/django_blog/source

Comment: you're welcome! i'll add it as an answer, just for completeness

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can **specify a directory to gunicorn to switch to before the apps are loaded**.

Simply add `--chdir /path/to/directory` to the launch.

In your case this might look as follows:

```
/root/sites/django_blog/virtualenv/bin/gunicorn --chdir /root/sites/django_blog/source --bind unix:/tmp/django_blog.socket django_blog.wsgi:application
```

Here is the [link](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#chdir) to the specific gunicorn settings documentation.

*Hope that helps and happy coding!*